# IF Statement Inside Function

Tags: php, function, if-statement, pdo

I am writing a if statement that if the two dates listed are equal  it echo's the first date and if the they aren't(else statement) it echoes "date1-date2" I have it inside a function and I do not know if I am alowed to do that.Here is the error I am getting

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF

Here is my function:

```
function getfevent ($conn) { 
$sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `event` WHERE `featured` = 0 LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$statement=$conn->prepare($sql); 
$statement->execute(); 
while($row=$statement->fetch()) {
$eventname = $row['name'];
$row_id=geteventid ($conn,$eventname);
$row_end=geteventend ($conn,$eventname);
$date=if ($row_id == $row_end){
    echo $row_id;
}
    else {
    echo $row_id " - " $row_end; 
}
?>
<?php echo "<td>$eventname</td><td>$date</td></tr>"; ?>
<?php
} 
} 
getfevent($conn);
```

Comment: Go thorough **[posting coding problem](http://sscce.org)**. Paste your code in such a way so that people can directly execute it.

Comment: what @MD.SahibBinMahboob

Comment: Your code snippet needs to have mysql connection established and also some returns from db after executing a query so people need to **edit** your script before **executing** it. It's good to post a **copy-paste-execute** ready code so that people can start helping you right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want this.

```
$date = $row_id == $row_end ? $row_id : $row_id . " - " . $row_end;
echo $date;
```

Don't forget. Use `.` to concat.

It's the same of

```
if ($row_id == $row_end) {
    $date = $row_id;
} else {
    $date = $row_id . " - " . $row_end;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course If statements are allowed inside functions. Your problem is that you are setting your variable `$date`'s value to the value of a `T_IF`, which is illegal.

Rather, you could do something like this:

```
$date=($row_id == $row_end);
if($date)
{
    echo $row_id;
}
else {
    echo $row_id." - ".$row_end; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$date=if ($row_id == $row_end){
    echo $row_id;
}
    else {
    echo $row_id " - " $row_end; 
}
```

Try:

```
$date;
if ($row_id == $row_end)
    $date=$row_id;
else
    $date=$row_id." - ".$row_end;
```

What you're doing in the original code is essentially telling PHP to set the value of variable `$date` to an if statement, which is, well, not possible.

The alternate piece of code creates a new variable `$date`, and then sets its value to `$row_id` or `$row_id." - ".$row_end;` depending on how the if statement evaluates.

Comment: That works but on the second to last line I got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: That would be the periods missing between the strings in the original code- edited the post, should work now.

Answer (score 0):

The echo statement is used to print something to the output buffer.

you have to do this instead:

```
if ($row_id == $row_end) {
    $date = something
} else {
    $date = somethingElse
}
//do whatever you want with $date
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$date=$row_id;
if ($row_id != $row_end)
{
    $date.=" - ".$row_end;
}
```

which should be much shorter i gues

Comment: You mean `$date.=" - ".$row_end`;